# MVC Custom Filter to Authorize User and send some response back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, filter

I have a special scenario where in I need to authorize all the users to check whether they can execute the controller method or not. If he is not authorized to perform an operation. I need to send back some message back to view to indicate the same. I need to cater below scenario. An item is assigned to an user and only that user can make changes(Assign to others/ Cancel etc..) to that item and others cannot perform it. On the other hand other user can try to first assign than item to themselves and perform operations on it. So the 2 cases which I need to capture is

1. When a user tries to assign the item to self that is not assigned to him then I need to send some response back to view indicating that the item is locked by XXX user and provide user to override it.
2. When a user tries to perform other operations on an item that is not assigned to him then just send some message response back to view

I tried creating a custom authorization filter using AuthorizeAttribute and AuthorizeCore, but when the authorization fails it is trying to redirect to Login screen. which I don't need. I need to send back some useful info back.

Hope I am clear. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried creating a custom authorization filter using
>   AuthorizeAttribute and AuthorizeCore, but when the authorization fails
>   it is trying to redirect to Login screen. which I don't need.

You could override the [`HandleUnauthorizedRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method and return whatever ActionResult you want. For example if you wanted to render an error view you could return a ViewResult:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var viewResult = new ViewResult();
    viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml";
    filterContext.Result = viewResult;
}
```